# I am trying to setup my roland td-3 drum kit as a MIDI controller

Tags: recording, drums, ableton-live, electronic-drumset

So far I've setup the kit in ableton live 10 as remote control and turned local control off on the kit itself. I've been following the guide in ableton step by step so far but failing at 'verifying the remote control setup' stage. I can't see MIDI controller verification light flashing when I hit the pads or the incoming MIDI meter flashing. I can chose the 'Launch control input' in the MIDI From drop down and MIDI to, and I can arm the track for MIDI recording with the little red button, which suggests the device is being recongnised but for some reason the signals from the pads aren't. Can anyone suggest a way of troubleshooting this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using it in another programs?

Comment: Hi, yes in garageband. Both times we were using a midi to USB then a USB to USB-C adaptor, do you know if this could affect the signal, the kit is old but usually output works fine?

Comment: The signal is probably fine, but Ableton likely doesn't like you using so many adapters. Maybe try using it with Reaper and see if it works? Garageband isn't exactly a very big DAW.